# What is the meaning of the expression "vampire rapist"?

Tags: expressions

Does it mean: 
A rapist which is also a vampire
or:
Someone who rapes vampires

or could it mean both?

Answer (score 1):

It can mean both, and thus depends entirely on context.

- *Van Helsing, the famous vampire rapist*
- *Count Dracula, the famous vampire rapist*

The relationship between two nouns within a noun group is usually variable; a related German example is *Orangensaft* ('orange juice') vs *Hustensaft* ('cough juice', ie medicine). That is unsurprising, as there are a variety of relationships that can be expressed, such as purpose, origin, properties, etc.